# Alert from servlet returns blank page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have a login page with a login servlet in which if the user enters wrong credentials, an alert is given:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("alert('User or password incorrect, please try again');");
        out.println("</script>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

the alert works fine, but after alert, it gives a blank page with the link :

http://localhost:8080/AWSCustomerJavaWebFinal/LoginServlet

What is the possible solution for this, so that after the alert, the page stays on login.jsp or forwards to login.jsp after the alert, rather than moving forward to the login servlet, I tried request dispatcher but then it did not show the alert and moved to login.jsp again.

Comment: this is not a good way to handle input validation.  try looking at how Frameworks such as Struts, Spring MVC or Stripes do it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am using hibernate for now, still in the learning phase.

Comment: try this form validation tutorial http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076076/java-web-development/server-side-java--advanced-form-processing-using-jsp.html

Comment: what is the HTML rendered ?

Comment: @ArushiTomar if you go with the provided code one thin you can do is add a `href` link to your login page with in the `<html>` you are writing back. Then after alert, the page will contain the link and you can navigate manually to login page.

Comment: @TomSebastian but after alert it gives a blank page, so I don't see the link in the page.

Comment: @ArushiTomar How did you try it. Please paste `out.println("<body><a href=\"your login url\">login</a></body>");` after `out.println("</head>");` in your code then try

Comment: @TomSebastian This worked but was not what I needed. Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **insist** of showing an alert to the user as a result of this `POST` operation, you should consider doing the redirect in javascript as well:

```
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    out.println("alert('User or password incorrect, please try again');");
    out.println("window.location = 'login.jsp';");
    out.println("</script>");
```

You might also want to think about adding at least a basic <body> to that response.

Comment: Thanks Jan. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that when you POST a form to a servlet, the servelt will validate the data.  if it fails then the servlet will add an attribute to the session and redirect back to the jsp page, other wise it will redirect to the main page

In all cases the JSP will check for this session attribute, if it does not exist, then it means it is normal (first try login) otherwise it means it has tried before and failed and it will display the error.

if you really really want an alert, then set a hidden field (with a html id) with the value of this session attribute.  The Javascript (onLoad/ready) will check this html element and display an alert if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, you gave a url in `action` attribute. On submission the form will be sent to that url. Which means you are now directed to that url. So it will stay on the url you provided.

Either provide same action url (login.jsp) and if authenticated then redirect user to another page
Or use ajax to do this stuff.

Comment: i was already doing that, if(result==true){ dispatch to a jsp page and if result is false then i was sending to an error page and it was working fine, but i wanted  to show an alert so i did this, there is no way that i can show the alert and send to login.jsp together?